# Symplectic structure of character varieties

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, symplectic-geometry

I would like to study character varieties $\mathrm{Hom}(\Gamma,G)/G$, where $\Gamma=\langle a_1,...,a_{2g} | \Pi_{i=1}^g [a_{2i-1},a_{2i}]\rangle$ is the fundamental group of a closed surface of genus $g$ and $G$ is a connected Lie group acting by conjugation on the set of homomorphisms from $\Gamma$ to $G$. First I have to understand the motivation from the deformations of holonomies of $(G,X)$-structures.

What I already 'know': $\mathrm{Hom}(\Gamma,G)$ is a submanifold of $G^{2g}$ with possible singularities (an algebraic variety when $G$ is an algebraic group). In general, $\mathrm{Hom}(\Gamma,G)/G$ is not Hausdorff (unless $G$ is compact), nor smooth. If $G$ is reductive, we can restrict to reductive representations to get a nice quotient. See [The Symplectic Nature of Fundamental Groups of Surfaces](http://www.math.umd.edu/%7Ewmg/SymplecticNature.pdf)

If $G$ is compact and simply connected, $\mathrm{Hom}(\Gamma,G)$ is connected (thus $\mathrm{Hom}(\Gamma,G)/G$ too). If $G=\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$, with a help of Toledo invariant and a Milnor-Wood inequality, $\mathrm{Hom}(\Gamma,G)/G$ has a finite number of connected components.

> How to study these topics from differential geometry view point without heavy use of GIT and algebraic groups theory. I do appreciate any hints, with textbooks or nice survey articles.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: These are way too many questions for a single post. Split your question in 4.

Comment: OK, I will edit my previous post.

Comment: These are all good questions and Goldman’s paper, while dated, is a good starting point.

Comment: @MoisheKohan May you suggest me some more recent references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a more modern reference, comparing to Goldman's paper,  one can use

[F. Labourie, Lectures on
Representations
of Surface Groups.](https://math.unice.fr/%7Elabourie/preprints/pdf/surfaces.pdf)
EMS publishing house, pp.145,
2013, Zurich Lectures in Advanced Mathematics.

These notes provide a substantial background material on the subject.

In general, whenever $G$ is a real algebraic Lie group (pretty much any group which you will think of will fit the bill), then for every finitely-generated group $\Gamma$,
$$
Hom(\Gamma,G)
$$
has finitely many connected components. Compactness of $G$ is irrelevant. However, if you want to count these components (provided that $\Gamma$ is a surface group), or, more generally, understand their topology, then you will need some differential geometry tools (Higgs bundles). See for instance:

Peter B. Gothen, [Representations of surface groups and Higgs bundles](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.0568).

*Wentworth, Richard A.*, [**Higgs bundles and local systems on Riemann surfaces**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-33578-0_4), Álvarez-Consul, Luis (ed.) et al., Geometry and quantization of moduli spaces. Based on 4 courses, Barcelona, Spain, March – June 2012. Basel: Birkhäuser/Springer (ISBN 978-3-319-33577-3/pbk; 978-3-319-33578-0/ebook). Advanced Courses in Mathematics – CRM Barcelona, 165-219 (2016). [ZBL1388.30052](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1388.30052).

Comment: many thanks. The Labourie notes are valuable, although its treatment of surfaces is not standard, it uses Ribbon graphs...

Comment: I will start with some examples $\Gamma=\pi_1(T^2)=\mathbb{Z}^2$ (genus $1$) and $G$ the $2$-dimensional affine group (then Heisenberg) before the reductive cases (SL(2), GL(2), SU(2)). Studying the action of the mapping class group of the surface on the connected components de the character variety, seems to be very interesting...

Comment: @Anonymous  Just keep in mind that the torus case is exceptional in many ways.

Comment: May you say more about the torus case (or suggest some references). The following survey paper by Gothen is interesting (in the case of $SL(2)$, using Toledo invariant) [link](http://www.cim.pt/magazines/bulletin/9/article/76/pdf)